# prepared statement / sql-injection preventation on variable from

Tags: javascript, java, t-sql

I read about that prepare statments are a good way to avoid sql injections to databases.
the problem is the Customer wants a quiet variable UI
where he first selects a table, then some contraints consisting of a column and a text.
So basically the (naive) endproduct will look like this:

```
Select * from %TABLENAME% where %ATTRIBUTENAME% = %VALUE%
```

Now the question is how to get this secure?

I could, of course, build a prepare Statement solution where I create statements for all tables in advance, but that sounds to me like a pretty stupid idea, because the effort to maintain this would be quiet big (the customer has quiet a few tables).
Any idea how to solve this in a secure manner that is as generic as possible?

Comment: And yes I know that the customer could come to the idea to not do an equals but a negativ or a like operation, but that is the least of my troubles so please no answes that mainly focus on the weakness of the description here because I simplified it a bit on purpose

Comment: A **Statement** is normally only used when there's no input from the user. Otherwise, use a **PreparedStatement**. Even with proper input sanitation, **Statement** isn't going to be secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your example to

```
select * from %TABLENAME% where %ATTRIBUTENAME% = ?
```

So that at least the `VALUE` can't be used for SQL injection. You could then have validation for `TABLENAME` and `ATTRIBUTENAME` against the known tables and columns in your database.

See [DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) which you might use in your validation at runtime. Or perhaps you might keep a static file, generated at build time, with the valid tables/columns.

You could generate an `Enum` at build time for every table/column combination? I know [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) does this sort of build time java code generation from a db schema... perhaps it can help?

Eg

```
public enum TableColumn {
    CUSTOMER_NAME("customer", "name"), CUSTOMER_ID("customer", "id"),
    ORDER_ID("order", "id"), // etc etc

    String table;
    String column;

    public TableColumn(String table, String column) {
        // set values
    }
}

public List<Row> doSelect(TableColumn tc, Object value) {
    String sql = String.format("select * from %s where %s = ?", tc.table, tc.column);
    Connection con = getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setObject(1, value);
        ...
```

Comment: Sounds great, I will need to review it internally, if i can convince my collegues, i will mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @Aeglasin When validating table names, you might want to limit the user to _user_, not system, tables. (User views may also be fair game.) Once you have a valid table name, you can validate the column name against the table. To add an extra layer of confusion, you could tag appropriate tables, columns and views using [`sp_addextendedproperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql) to allow users access to an even more limited subset of data.